# Спойлер на WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

Требуется создать нечто вроде спойлера на WPF-форме. То есть группу контролов, объединённых одним назначением, которую можно скрыть. Из стандартных компонентов счёл наиболее подходящим TreeView. Сейчас это выглядит так:

[image: Так выглядит]

1. Есть ли более подходящие компоненты для этой цели?
2. Если нет, как грамотно создать привязку?

Для хранения данных имеется такой класс:

```
class Variable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Min { get; set; }
    public string Max { get; set; }
    public string UnitSymbol { get; set; }
    public bool Display { get; set; }
    public Variable(string name, string symbol, string value, string min, string max, string unitSymbol, bool display)
    {
        Name = name;
        Symbol = symbol;
        Value = value;
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
        UnitSymbol = unitSymbol;
        Display = display;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [`Expander`](http://wpftutorial.net/Expander.html). Привязки внутри контента делаются как обычно.